# Is there a way to store and manipulate a span of time that takes month lengths, leap years, etc. into account?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, standards, string-formatting, timespan

I was just about to write this myself, but I know this has to exist and I'm just managing to avoid all the Google keywords that would lead me right to it.

I would be looking for something like DDDMMMYYY where D, M, Y are the number of days, months, and years. So 00103000 would indicate a span of three months and one day, or 000000001 would indicate a span of one year. Ideally this format would also have a standard way to apply it that could take into consideration all of the pitfalls of timespan calculation like varying number of days in a month, leap years, etc.

I am not looking for a way to calculate a timespan between two known timestamps, as was asked here ([Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)), i'm looking for something like a specific string format I can store that would indicate a span of time to be used for determining a second unknown date from a known one.

Such as, using my fictitious format above: if I said "calculate what date would be 00103000 from September 15, 2009" would return "December 16, 2009", which is three months and one day after September 15th.

Comment: While I myself am using C#.net and MS SQL 2008 for development, I'd be interested in any implementation of such a format.

Comment: What's "one year after" a Feb 29? What's "one year before" the result of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the [ISO 8061](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) format for durations.  It is not only easy to parse and apply to a given date, it is a well-known standard with a lot of resources available.

Determining the duration from two points in time is a bit trickier, but only because without input from the application, it is unclear whether 1-March to 1-June is 3 months or 92 days.  Nonetheless, the format can express either equally well as well as, for example, 0.25 years.

Comment: Yes! The ISO 8061 Duration is exactly what I was looking for, and there are plenty of parsing methods out there that handle month and leap year issues. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that's good to know.  I knew about representing exact times in ISO 8601, but didn't know it covered intervals as well.

Comment: That said... in memory, you still may want to convert the duration to seconds.

Comment: I agree with keeping seconds whenever it makes sense.  In my most recent case, the duration was for reporting "events in the last month," so I could not just keep the duration in seconds since the number of seconds in "the last month" varied depending on when the user executed the report.

Comment: and this too is exactly my predicament. The users want to see "last year" "last month", how it has to be calculated be damned.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most common representation of this is a numeric: the number of seconds in the time span (which may or may not be fractional, depending on your needs).  Many time libraries already [represent time as seconds since the epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Encoding_time_as_a_number), so this makes addition and subtraction of time trivial.  The only major issue of concern is overflows (e.g. [year 2038 bug](http://www.2038bug.com/)).

Comment: Yes, this would be great for indicating a firm number of seconds, but I would be looking for something that could handle the human constructs of months and years, and take into account variable month lengths and leap years.

Comment: Just to clarify.  You can represent month-long or even decade-long durations in seconds.  The nice thing about representing durations in seconds is that you can be as precise or imprecise as you want to be.